# How to encrypt the SqlLite database/Table and save it to internal storage to use it later

Tags: java, android, sqlite, encryption

I am trying to solve a problem in which I want to save the whole "SqlLite database" (Used in my app) to my local internal/external storage in an encrypted format (preferable AES128) so, it can be later decrypted and used by importing it back to my app if required.

I am not sure how to do that in android.
Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library called [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher).

It supports 256-bit AES encryption.

You have to provide a Master Key that will be used to encrypt the data.

It is a little bit [outdated](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/tutorial-add-sqlcipher-to-your-android-app/) but it will give you some ideas to implement it.

If you want to use it with Room, check [this](https://sonique6784.medium.com/protect-your-room-database-with-sqlcipher-on-android-78e0681be687) out.